# Porque o Bot Comunidade apaga as tags "destaque" toda hora?

Tags: suporte, tags

Estava olhando essa [publicação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/7785/revisions), e reparei que o bot da comunidade estava excluindo a tag *destaque*, ficou uma "guerra" entre o mod adicionando e ele retirando.

O que seria isso especificamente? é uma tag que tem prazo?

Comment: Complementando, a tag "destaque" é o que faz com que as coisas apareçam no quadrinho amarelo de mesmo nome (destaque) na lateral da página.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

De acordo com [esta resposta no Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281798/401803), existe um script automático que roda uma vez por semana.

Mais precisamente, todo sábado, à meia-noite em UTC, o script remove a tag [destaque](/questions/tagged/destaque) das perguntas em que foi colocada há mais de 30 dias.

Como não roda todo dia, pode ser que demore mais de 30 dias para ser removida, mas de qualquer forma, se nenhum moderador remover a tag manualmente, o sistema o faz automaticamente.

Answer (score 4):

Não tem guerra alguma, é automação. Olhe as datas. O moderador colocar e 5 semanas (acho) depois ele retira, porque este é o prazo que fica sem que alguém vá lá tirar. Ocorre só nesta *tag*.