# Posts em destaque do Meta não estão aparecendo no site principal

Tags: bug, status-pronto

Notei que na página inicial estávamos sem destaques do nosso Meta

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imaginei que as tags haviam expirado, já que [o sistema faz uma remoção periódica](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8825/70), mas ocorre que [as tags estão nas postagens ainda](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/destaque):

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: parece resolvido, vamos ver se permanece